# What causes "InnoDB: Corruption of an index tree" error

Tags: mysql, innodb

Today I experienced this error a second time in two weeks and I wonder why that is?

Is it more a hardware- or software-related thing? (e.g. what should I check?)

That DB server didn't have any problems until now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't you have this message in log?

> This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this
>   binary or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt,
>   improperly built, or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by
>   malfunctioning hardware. We will try our best to scrape up some info
>   that will hopefully help diagnose the problem, but since we have
>   already crashed, something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Comment: I do have this comment, but the hardware seems ok (disks, filesystem and memory), so any hints on other possible causes might be valuable...

Comment: There is a bug in mysql or some of it's libraries. Dump/restore table and upgrade system. If it won't help - post a bug to mysql bugtracker.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was that we had different mysql server versions in replication due to the fact that one server has a pending OS upgrade. I installed MariaDB, set up the replication, and everything works now